# wit.ai - Keywords conflict

Tags: wit.ai

I am designing a bot with wit.ai and encounter a conflict issue.
In my story the user wants instructions to access a service. I've created an entity service.
There are 2 services available "mailing" and "chat channels" but I want the user to be able to ask instructions for both at once.

Therefore, my entity service has "keywords" for search strategy and "mailing", "chat channels" and "both" as values.

But when I branch the story after the question the bot asks "to which I've added quick answers "mailing", "chat channels" and "both", but at this point I have a conflict between the branches.

When I test the bot on wit.ai, whatever my answer he goes to the "both" branch.
I'm struggling to find out why there is a conflict between the keywords, if someone could help me it would be great.

I've tried to train the bot with small variations of each answer but this doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Do you need to branch? Should working using more than one story.

Comment: That's a good question that I've asked myself when designing the bot. I've made a few bots with a lot of stories for every case but the bots ended up confusing stories and sending mixed answers.
I've made one story per case here and if I don't branch I will really have a lot of stories and I would have to duplicate large parts of stories.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution we came up with for this issue:

- instead of creating a new `story`, start by creating the `entity`of type `trait`in the `understanding` tab
- enter all possible values in the `understanding` tab
- once the entity has been properly created, you can use it in a `story`